# Why Angular 2 doesn't load default app-root component?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-cli

I'm trying to start Angular app generated via angular CLI, but it seems like the default `app-root` component doesn't load. Need to say, that I'm using proxy for connection between angular app and express server, and I'm running two scripts at the same time: `node bin/www` for express/node.js start and `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json` for starting Angular and creating proxy connection, it looks like this (the part of package.json):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"node bin/www\" \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json\""
}
```

The index page loads fine, but it seems that `app-root` component (the default component, which was created from angular CLI `ng new`) doesn't loading:
[image]
Here is my node.js/express `use`s and a route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static('./src/client/'));
app.use(express.static('./'));
app.use(express.static('./tmp'));
app.use('/*', express.static(path.resolve('src/client/index.html')));

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('src/client/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the structure of my project (if needed):
[image]

What did I miss? Why the default `app-root` component doesn't loading? (need to say, when I run `ng serve`, it starts the angular homepage as needed and the component is OK, so I think the problem is somewhere in express).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `Ng Serve` and serving from express are duplicative.   Even so, you would serve from the build folder, not the src folder.

Comment: @TaylorAckley, I have tried to start only express and to use build folder called "dist" by default, but still having the same problem (but now all scripts are loaded).

Comment: @Ced, here are my received `index.html`: https://ibb.co/czJe2k, and my network tab: https://ibb.co/hE3Jv5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should serve the contents of the `dist/` folder [after calling `ng build --prod` (the `--prod` is important, as the default is --dev)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds). So, it would be something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng build --prod && node bin/www"
}
```

And, more or less adapting your express script:

```
app.use(express.static('./dist'));
app.use('/*', express.static(path.resolve('dist/index.html')));

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion looks OK, but I have tried to use it and now I'm getting 404 error. Maybe you misspelled somewhere or forgot to include something to your answer? I feel, your suggestion is very close. Need to say, that I'm totally new to node/express

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot adding `index.html`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have tried, the index.html with scripts loads fine, but i still getting an empty `app-root` element. But my build result (`dist` folder) contains only `client/index.html` and five `...bundle.js` files. All of them are included in `index.html`, but when I trying to open one of them in new tab, I don't see any code as expected. Seems like they wasn't really included. I think, this is another one problem, but if you have any thoughts about it, please, let me know

Comment: Hm.. Seems like so. The behavior is different from when you run `ng serve`? Shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, they are different. Anyway, I'll try to find the final solution by myself, you get me closer to the right solution. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, OK. Just don't forget you need to serve the `/dist/` content, not the `/src/`.